# Layout: HTML + CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="content" id="content">
        <div class='nav'>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>One</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Two</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Three</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Four</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Five</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='innercontent'>
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
.content {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 190px;
    padding: 30px;
}
.nav {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 140px; 
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.nav a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.nav li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #369;
    padding: 4px 5px;
    margin: 8px; 0px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav ul {
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.innercontent {
    top: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Problem: The second div (innercontent)'s top should exactly line up with the first ul's top. What have I done wrong?

Comment: What goes wrong in the first place? Do we need to guess?

Comment: Did you see my last line? It is a question right: What should I do to make both divs line up (vertcally)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things and you're done:

```
add float:left; to .nav
change margin:20px; in .innercontent
```

so in the end it should look like

```
.nav {
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 140px; 
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
}

.innercontent {
    top: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

The float is necessary so `.innercontent` can float around `.nav`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `vertical-align:top;` for the content. By default the `vertical-align` is set to `baseline`.

Answer (score 1):

add `float:left` for both `.nav` and `.innercontent`

I see that you use `top` property for `.innercontent` but keep in mind that this properties are used only with positioned elements (`relative`,`absolute`,`fixed`)

I suggest you to read the following two articles to understand how `position` and `float` works:

[CSS Floats 101](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101/) & [CSS Positioning 101](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/).

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/GYPJH/

Comment: I know, I did not mean the top property, but the top in general sense.

Comment: @Hidde I just saw in `.innercontent` the following `top: 0px;`. For this reason I mentioned the above.

Comment: Haha, you are right, I am sorry! I was testing all things I could come up with myself, and I had not deleted that line yet.